# Eiffel: a way to get target and project name @runtime

Tags: eiffel

Is there a way to get the project name and target at execution time or is it not stored into executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project and target names are not stored in an executable.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround Setting the executable name into `project settings -> target -> Output name` and getting it from following function made me able to do something similar

```
application_file_name: STRING
    local
        l_path: PATH
    once
        Result := {EXECUTION_ENVIRONMENT}.arguments.argument (0).out
        create l_path.make_from_string (Result)
        check
            attached l_path.entry as l_fname_path
        then
            Result := l_fname_path.utf_8_name
        end
    ensure
        instance_free: Class
    end
```